# Changing Control property in foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to force controls in a `TableLayoutPanel` to be enabled (I disable the controls individually before).

Using this code does not change anything (I remember foreach can not effect the items that are being looped over!). I guess there should be some casting or something to make it work:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in myTable.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Enabled = true;
}
```

`myTable` is itself inside another table...if it is needed to be pointed out. The controls I want to enable again are of type `TextBox` and `DomainUpDown`.

Comment: FYI you can *affect* (eg. change a string property from "Foo" to "Bar") the items in a collection, just not remove them or insert new items. What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Posted code should work.  Are the controls inside another container?  Is myTable enabled?  Is myTable in a parent container that is disabled?

Comment: Yes, `myTable` is itself inside a table, how to fix it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sorry for bothering...apparently after scratching my head for few hours I found that the problem was because the table itself was set to `Enabled = false` somewhere in the code. I took care of that and the problem is solved. Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that shows you can adjust the property like you are looking to do. But you cannot change the reference you are iterating over itself. Try this out and see if it clarifies anything.

```
public class BasicClass
{
    public int BasicProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BasicClass> lst = new List<BasicClass>();
        lst.Add(new BasicClass {BasicProperty=5});
        lst.Add(new BasicClass { BasicProperty = 6 });
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            item.BasicProperty++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", lst[0].BasicProperty, lst[1].BasicProperty);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout` isn't a control container, despite the fact that it seems so.  So, you should iterate some other container to find your controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //MyparentControl is the parent control of myTable
     //so assuming 0 is the index of "myTable" 

     for (int h = 0; h < MyparentControl.Controls[0].Controls.Count; h++)
        {
            MyparentControl.Controls[0].Controls[h].Enabled = true;
        }
```